# Generic JSON Element Access

Tags: javascript, json

My colleague wrote a function to get all the keys out of a JSON object and check them against ones we're interested in. What I can't seem to search Google correctly for is how to take the variable holding the key name and use it to get the values. Obviously, idx itself is not a member of the object, but it contains the member name. How do I use idx to access obj?

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data[0][i]), function(idx, obj){
            for(var j = 0; j < searchKeys.length; j++){
                if (idx == searchKeys[j]) {
                    //How do I do this correctly?
                    injectLoc.innerHTML += panelMaker(obj.idx, idx, "green", "gears");
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `obj[idx]`?

Comment: I had not. My background is mostly C++, and every w3schools page or other little guides just access with "property name", so these little tricks (and their names) elude me when it comes to JS.

Comment: @patrickjp93 welcome to JavaScript! It's a really fun language with some fun and weird idiosyncrasies. MDN is a nice JavaScript resource. Wait until you see something like, `if(obj) { /* some code */}`. Confused the hell outta me when I first saw it.

Comment: I think the thing I hate most is the sheer lack of good debugging tools out there. I want Clang-Fuzz for JavaScript!

Comment: @patrickjp93 chrome and firefox have pretty good debugging tools. You can put a break-point in the code and use the console and watch window for any variable value tracking you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it similar to how you'd access an element on an array.

`var value = obj[idx]`;

You can access a property on an object in JavaScript like `obj.prop` or `obj["prop"]` or `obj[idx]` where `idx === "prop"`.

Comment: `.` notation can be used only when your object does have those property and same goes for the `[]` notation but `[]` notation comes handy when you have the property in a variable.

Comment: `[]` syntax for accessing object attributes is also useful when the attribute name is not a valid JavaScript identifier, like `123abc`.  (`obj.123abc` is a syntax error, but `obj["123abc"]` works.)

Comment: So, if idx = "Count" and I code obj[idx], does it return the same as if I'd coded obj["Count"]?

Comment: @patrickjp93 If `idx === "Count"`, then `obj[idx] === obj["Count"]`, and `obj["Count"] === obj.Count`.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON,

```
Accessing elements by index --> obj[idx]
Accessing values by keys --> obj.key or obj["key"]
Note: If key has spaces use only --> obj["key"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.keys() to iterate keys of the object. So the function could potentially work like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
  if(index === key){
    injectLoc.innerHTML += panelMaker(obj[key], index, "green", "gears");
  }
})
```

Comment: if(key === key_we_want) { injectLoc.innerHTML += panelMaker(obj[key], key, "green", "gears");

Comment: You got the syntax right. Just need a bit of logic code to see where and how you pass 'KEY_YOU_WANT' as the condition.